# Computer Lags at Startup

Tags: windows, windows-xp, boot

I have been experience lags when booting my computer up and did not know if there is anything I need to do or be concerned about. Here are the details:

I boot my computer up and I require a password that must be entered. I type the password and hit enter. Then normally I will see a blue screen for no more than a few seconds before windows load. But there are times when it will take 15 - 30 min before windows will actually load. There have been no changes to windows or updates etc when this happens. Any ideas as to why this happens or what I can do to prevent this?

Note: I am running Windows XP (SP3)

Comment: run a chkdsk /r on the hard drive, from the command prompt in Windows or from a XP install disc...http://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=5097

Comment: Also scan for viruses using a boot cd....http://connect.microsoft.com/systemsweeper

Comment: That is a really bad delay, how does the system act once it is all running? How does the drive that the system is on, act when it comes to file copying and specific disk activity?

Comment: @Moab - Ran `chkdsk /r` and everything was fine. I have checked for viruses since this began but I will check again.

Comment: @Psycogeek - Once the computer boots it runs fine without issues. It is a touch slow but this is an old computer and the slow is nothing new and I highly doubt related to the boot issue.

Comment: Then it is a high chance it is a driver that is enumerated, and the hardware doesn't respond. Try booting into some of the other Modes F8 F8 , there is a step-by step mode that can somewhat help in seeing where it is at in boot.  BootVis , boot tracing, can also track the driver load, and give Clues, (and false leads too).  clear the prefetcher folder , analyze the whole startup list, via AutoRuns or HijackThis.  Make a Full backup of the Disk anyway, if your starting to have real hardware issues do not risk it.

Comment: @Psycogeek - Thanks for the information. I will backup as a precaution. And I will look into the rest. If I find an answer I will post it here.